# How to store a collection in ASP.NET Session using Azure Redis Session State Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, azure, session-state

I am using `Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider` with Redis Cache configured on Azure, in ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

And I'm talking about storing values in `Session` in some action defined in controller. It works fine if I store primitive values (`Session["Foo"]="Bar"`) or collection of primitives:

```
List<int> items = new List<int>();
items.Add(5);
Session["Items"] = items;
```

But if I try to store collection of my own class, it doesn't persist (after another request, `Session["Products"]` is `null`):

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
products.Add(db.Find(Id));
Session["Products"] = products;
```

Class `Product` looks like that:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

What should I do to store instances of this class in session?

Answer (score 2):

Since Redis is a Key-Value store, your objects need to be serialized to a `byte[]` stream. Try to decorate your `Product` class with the `[Serializable]` attribute.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn690521.aspx#Objects).

Comment: Try to wrap your `new List<Product>();` in another class that is marked with `[Serializable]`.

Answer (score 0):

@lort, I think the problem you might be facing is the following. **The session dictionary in Redis when using Redis session state provider is itself a Hash where each session key value pair is a hash field/value pair and can take only strings as values and NOT objects such as lists as far as I know**. As @haim770 pointed out, you can convert the list into something like JSON or XML and write that JSON/XML as a string. When you want to use the Session variable (that list), convert the JSON/XML string value back to list.

For example, see below.I am using Microsoft Redis Session State provider *Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider*.

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
products.Add(new Product{Name="test", Description="test"});
string productsField = ser.Serialize(products);
Session["Products"] = productsField;
```

In redis-cli window, I can see the session value for list of products displayed. Please note that the session dictionary is a Redis Hash and each "entry" is one Hash field.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall /SessionInRedis_nnl24530afhndnchb2f3ronc_Data
1) "loginTime"
2) "\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01
\x00\x00\x00\x149/25/2014 7:52:03 PM\x0b"
3) "UserName"
4) "\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01
\x00\x00\x00\x06prasad\x0b"
5) "Products"
6) "\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x01
\x00\x00\x00&[{\"Name\":\"test\",\"Description\":\"test\"}]\x0b"
```

Hope this helps (the OP or maybe someone else) although the question is old.